# Click button quickly push UIViewController twice

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

**example:**

I have two buttons in current view, when I click the button it will push a `UIViewController` in the current `UINavgitionController`.

This is my code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(pvc, animated: true)
})
```

But I found a bug. When I click the button quickly, the `UIViewController` push twice, why does that happen?

PS: Now, I have used this code in lots of `UIViewController`s, more than 200 times.

Comment: With your code, it will happen.  `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` doesn't execute immediately. You can disable the button after you click it.

Comment: @anhtu is right. Hope you do understand the concept of Asynchronous and Synchronous calls.

Comment: Right now when you tap it twice, it sends you command twice to the queue. As with Asynchronous calls, each of them gets called when its time for them to to run, resulting in pushing the VC twice.

Comment: if you are clicking on button two times then it will navigate two times.. so you have put loader or activity indicator until the control navigate to the screen...

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same issue, i resolved it by creating category of UIButton which will only take exclusive touch.

Create Category of UIButton

```
#import <objc/runtime.h> //Please import

    @implementation UIButton (ExclusiveTouch)

    + (void)load
    {
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            Class class = [self class];

            SEL originalSelector = @selector(willMoveToSuperview:);
            SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(inc_willMoveToSuperview:);

            Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
            Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);

            BOOL didAddMethod =
            class_addMethod(class,
                            originalSelector,
                            method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
                            method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

            if (didAddMethod) {
                class_replaceMethod(class,
                                    swizzledSelector,
                                    method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                                    method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
            } else {
                method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
            }
        });
    }

    - (void)inc_willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview
    {
        // This is correct and does not cause an infinite loop!
        // See the link for an explanation
        [self inc_willMoveToSuperview:newSuperview];

        [self setExclusiveTouch:YES];
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell me How to use it ? @ROCKING-XCode